# Filter my home page posts by category or by tag

Tags: customization, query-posts

Would like to filter my home page posts by category **OR** by tag.

i.e. only posts that are in category "X" or have tag "B" appear on the home page.

Have used code below successfully to filter (include/exclude) just by category

```
function exclude_category($query) {
if ( $query->is_home ) {
$query->set('cat', '3');
}
return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category');
```

then tried to add the tag filter by replacing `$query->set('cat', '3');` with
`$query->set(('cat', '3')||(is_tag('urgent'));`

no good - did not work.

Can this be done ? How ?

Any ideas, help or advice much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code to list the posts that are categorized under category id 3 OR have tag 'urgent'

```
function exclude_category($query) {
    if ( $query->is_home ) {
        $query->set( 'tax_query', array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' =>  'ID',
                'terms' => 3
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'urgent'
            )
        ));
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category');
```